# Elastic Search Synonyms - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, elasticsearch-rails

I'm using Ruby on Rails with the elasticsearch-rails gem and I am trying to use a synonyms filter. I have been following the question posted here for guidance (my implementation works as expected except for the synonym part):

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/issues/63

Here is my code:

```
settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 },
    analysis: {
  filter: {
    synonym: {
      type: "synonym",
      ignore_case: true,
      synonyms:[
        "roller,wheel"
      ]
    }
  },
  analyzer: {
    synonym: {
      tokenizer: "whitespace",
      filter: ["synonym", "lowercase", "stop", "snowball"]
    }
  }
} do
  mappings dynamic: 'false' do
    indexes :name, analyzer: 'synonym'
    indexes :status, analyzer: 'english'
    #indexes :description, analyzer: 'english' 
    indexes :part_number, analyzer: 'english'
    indexes :text, analyzer: 'english'
    indexes :normal_model, type: 'nested' do
      indexes :name, analyzer: 'english'
      indexes :number, analyzer: 'english'
      indexes :machine_type, analyzer: 'english'

      indexes :normal_brand, type: 'nested' do
        indexes :name, analyzer: 'english'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my code to search in my controller action:

```
 @products = Product.search(
        query: { 
          query_string: {
           #query: "*manual* AND status:\"Disabled\""
           #fields: ["normal_model.name", "normal_brand.name"],
            query: "*#{params[:q]}* AND status:\"Viewable On Website & Backend\""

            #query:  "*" + params[:q]+ "*"
          }
        }
      )
```

I have records with the name field set to "wheel" but when I search "roller" I get 0 results and NO errors. I would expect to retrieve the record with the name "wheel" at this point. I have also deleted the index entirely and verified that it was deleted and recreated my index as well to ensure I wasn't just facing an indexing issue. I am not real sure what to do at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Also here is my as_indexed_json method

```
def as_indexed_json(options={})
    as_json(
        only: [:name, :description, :part_number, :url_key, :image, :price, :shipping, :warranty, :eta, :status, :sku],
        include: { 
            normal_model: { only: [:name, :number, :machine_type],
                include: { 
                    normal_brand: { only: :name}
                }
            }
        }
    )
 end
```

Thanks

Update:

I've also tried adding the following code (suggested in the answer below) to my controller search action.

```
fields: ['name', '_all'],
query: "#{params[:q]} AND status:\"Viewable On Website & Backend\""
```

I put this code in place of my original code in the search action but this still did not produce any results when I searched the word "roller". I am still able to search "wheel" and retrieve several results but I am having no luck with the specified synonym.

Update:

Here is one of the documents containing the word "wheel" in the product name field.

```
{
  "_index" : "products",
  "_type" : "product",
  "_id" : "288374",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "name" : "wheel",
    "description" : "This is the O.E.M. wheel for the Spirit CE800 Elliptical with a model number 800049.",
    "shipping" : null,
    "sku" : "58511",
    "eta" : "3 to 5 Business Days",
    "warranty" : "1 Year",
    "part_number" : "N/A",
    "url_key" : "spirit-ce800-elliptical-model-800049-lubricant",
    "price" : 19.99,
    "image" : "noimage-main_20837.jpg",
    "status" : "Viewable On Website & Backend",
    "normal_model" : {
      "name" : "CE800",
      "number" : "800049",
      "machine_type" : "Elliptical",
      "normal_brand" : {
        "name" : "Spirit"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Update:

Here is my Product mapping

```
{
  "products" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "product" : {
        "dynamic" : "false",
        "properties" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "synonym"
          },
          "normal_model" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "machine_type" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "english"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "english"
              },
              "normal_brand" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                  "name" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "analyzer" : "english"
                  }
                }
              },
              "number" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "english"
              }
            }
          },
          "part_number" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "english"
          },
          "status" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "english"
          },
          "text" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "english"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your query, you are searching in the _all field. (default behaviour for query_string).

To use your synonym analyzer you must search also in the name field.
Like this :

```
  @products = Product.search(
    query: { 
      query_string: {
       fields: ['name', '_all'],
       query: "#{params[:q]} AND status:\"Viewable On Website & Backend\""
      }
    }
  )
```

If `params[:q]` contains "roller" you'll get your records containing **the word** "wheel".

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried this exactly as you stated and reindexed but it didn't work. The search returned no errors either. I've restarted the server as well. When I search "wheel" I get several results. When I search roller I still get none.

Comment: Weird, it should work. Can you please show in the OP your document (containing "wheel") _source.

Comment: I've updated the question with the document results directly from ElasticSearch.

Comment: I got it to work by changing query_string to multi_match. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Weird, it should work. You can force the analyzer on tour query_string : 'analyzer: :synonym'. Try it to check the analyzer